# import cv2 in python in vs code not working

Tags: python, opencv, visual-studio-code

The python code I wanted to run:

```
import cv2
print(cv2.__verion__)
```

The Error code I am getting:

```
Windows PowerShell
    Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
    
    Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6
    
    PS D:\Programme\Visual Studio\New Projects> & C:/Users/Florian/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python.exe "d:/Programme/Visual Studio/New Projects/Python/opencv_test.py"
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "d:\Programme\Visual Studio\New Projects\Python\opencv_test.py", line 1, in <module>
        import cv2
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
```

But if I type the exact same code in the Terminal it works:

```
    PS D:\Programme\Visual Studio\New Projects> python
    Python 3.9.9 (tags/v3.9.9:ccb0e6a, Nov 15 2021, 18:08:50) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    >>> import cv2
    >>> print(cv2.__version__)
    4.5.4
    >>>
```

So far I installed python via Command Prompt and via Microsoft Store.
And currently I am running the verion 3.9.9

```
PS D:\Programme\Visual Studio\New Projects> python --version
Python 3.9.9
```

I installed opencv in the Command Prompt:

```
PS C:\Users\Florian> pip install opencv-python
Requirement already satisfied: opencv-python in c:\users\florian\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (4.5.4.60)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.19.3 in c:\users\florian\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from opencv-python) (1.21.5)
PS C:\Users\Florian>
```

I searched every Forum I could think of, but cant find a fix.

Please help

Comment: `C:/Users/Florian/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python.exe` You're using Python version 3.10, which does not have cv2 installed.

Comment: How can I install opencv for python version 3.10?

Comment: Is there a `pip.exe` in the same dierctory?  Try running that one specifically.

Answer (score 3):

in your VScode press Ctrl+Shift+P and then type "Python: Select Interpreter" then select your python Interpreter and Run it again.

Comment: Yeah, I was having the same issue and was using the python interpreter 3.10.1, however, I changed it to python interpreter 3.8.5 and it worked. I was hoping you might have figured out how to run it on more recent interpreters.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue in VScode using python 3.9.6. I switched to python 3.10.7 and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try running
`pip3.10 install opencv-python`.

Because:

- cv2 is a part of opencv-python
- and/or you might not have installed the module in the right python folder version.